# How to synchronize the time in Debian6 server? We have 30 min delay in our VMs

Tags: debian, ntp, time, time-synchronization, clock-synchronization

I can't have the correct time in our servers. We get always the same delay in the three of them (they are VM on the same server).

We use **ntp** to have our date always synchronized·

The main server which is virtualized has OS Linux Proxmox.

What I have probe in the main server:

Reconfigure tzdata *(real time 12:14 pm CEST)*:

```
root@ns226161:~# dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Madrid'
Local time is now:      Wed May 13 11:55:01 CEST 2015.
Universal Time is now:  Wed May 13 09:55:01 UTC 2015.
```

Try to access hardware clock *(time is okay here!!)*:

```
root@ns226161:~# hwclock -r
Wed 13 May 2015 14:01:57 CEST  -0.327412 seconds
```

Restart NTP:

```
root@ns226161:~# /etc/init.d/ntp restart
[ ok ] Stopping NTP server: ntpd.
[....] Starting NTP server: ntpd/etc/init.d/ntp: line 40: 11709 Terminated              lockfile-touch $LOCKFILE
. ok
```

So, **how can I update the time from the hardware clock which is okay?**

Comment: What's the virtualisation technology?

Comment: Yeah. That is normally totally fixed by properly installing the drivers for your visualization technology. Simple like that.

Comment: In the main server the time is of hwclock is Okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to this wiki: http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:syncing_hardware_clock_and_system_local_time

Sopping NTP, update time from their servers, restart ntp and synchronize HW clock

```
root@ns226161:~# /etc/init.d/ntp stop
Stopping NTP server: ntpd.
root@ns226161:~# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
13 May 14:06:12 ntpdate[16434]: step time server 37.187.2.84 offset 1117.077034 sec
root@ns226161:~# /etc/init.d/ntp start
Starting NTP server: ntpd.
root@ns226161:~# date
Wed May 13 14:06:30 CEST 2015
root@ns226161:~# hwclock --systohc --localtime
root@ns226161:~#
```